# What is the RegEx for finding 3 different numbers in consecutive lines?

Tags: regex

Let's say I have the following type of data:

```
[577]   {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}
[578]   {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}
[579]   {0x05,0x08,0x01,0x00,0x47,0x00,0x61,0x00,0x6c}
[580]   {0x05,0x08,0x01,0x00,0x47,0x00,0x61,0x00,0x6c}
[581]   {0x05,0x08,0x01,0x00,0x47,0x00,0x61,0x00,0x6c}
[582]   {0x04,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x61,0x00,0x78,0x00,0x79}
[583]   {0x04,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x61,0x00,0x78,0x00,0x79}
[584]   {0x04,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x61,0x00,0x78,0x00,0x79}
[585]   {0x04,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x61,0x00,0x78,0x00,0x79}
[586]   {0x04,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x61,0x00,0x78,0x00,0x79}
[587]   {0x04,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x61,0x00,0x78,0x00,0x79}
[588]   {0x03,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x53,0x00,0x32}
[589]   {0x03,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x53,0x00,0x32}
[590]   {0x03,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x53,0x00,0x32}
[591]   {0x03,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x53,0x00,0x32}
[592]   {0x02,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x32,0x00,0x2b,0x00,0x20}
[593]   {0x02,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x32,0x00,0x2b,0x00,0x20}
[594]   {0x02,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x32,0x00,0x2b,0x00,0x20}
[595]   {0x02,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x32,0x00,0x2b,0x00,0x20}
[596]   {0x02,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x32,0x00,0x2b,0x00,0x20}
[597]   {0x02,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x32,0x00,0x2b,0x00,0x20}
[598]   {0x01,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x2d,0x00,0x39,0x00,0x33}
[599]   {0x00,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x34,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}
[600]   {0x00,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x34,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}
[601]   {0x00,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x34,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}
[602]   {0x00,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x34,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}
```

The relevant data is between the braces { }.

I want to find where the first column doesn't repeat.

In the data above that would be for the row marked as "[598]".
Because row "[597]" start with a '0x02', and row "[599]" starts with a '0x00'. So the '0x01' is unique.

But it could very well be that the '0x01' is a '0x09'. I mean that the number per-se don't matter, as long as it's different from the lines above and below it. Only for the first column matters though.

I've been trying with Lookarounds but it doesn't work:

```
(?<!.*\{(\3).*\n)(.*\{(0x\d\d))(?!.*\n.*\{(\3))
```

Any ideas?

Notes:

- I'm using VSCode to find.
- No need to capture it, just would like it to highlight.

Comment: I don't think regex is the right tool for this... pick a script language, create an array with this data and a code to check that...

Comment: Why isn't it [579] because it starts with `0x05`, but the previous line starts with `0x00`? If you have to find a number that's unique in all the lines, I don't think you can do it easily with a regexp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following works for what you're after (slightly improved from Andrej, and adapted to support JavaScript's flavour regex, which I believe is what VSCode uses).

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BeisqG/1)

```
^\[\d+\]\s+{([^,]+)[^[]+^\[\d+\]\s+{((?!\1)[^,]+)[^[]+^\[\d+\]\s+{((?!\2)[^,]+)[^[]+$
```

---

Notes:

- JavaScript regex doesn't appear to support the `(?!\1|\3)` negative lookahead syntax, so I've swapped this for a single back reference 2-vs-1, and 3-vs-2

  - Due to this, if the first and third lines have the same value in the first element, then it'll still match, which isn't ideal...
- Matches full lines and fields, if you need/want to use this for processing too
- This is operating over three distinct lines:

  1. `^\[\d+\]\s+{([^,]+)[^[]+`

     - matches against the numeric component surrounded by `[]` brackets, and the first element in the `{}` braces
  2. `^\[\d+\]\s+{((?!\1)[^,]+)[^[]+`

     - matches the same again, but instead of "*the first value*", it explicitly forbids the value used on the first line
     - when compared with Andrej's answer, this will capture the full element due to `((?!\1)[^,]+)` vs `((?!\1).{4})`
  3. `^\[\d+\]\s+{((?!\2)[^,]+)[^[]+$`

     - same again, but explicitly forbids the value used on the second line

Answer (score 2):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/l9Im7L/1)):

```
^\[\d+\]\s+{([^,]+)[^{]+{((?!\1|\3).{4})[^{]+{((?!\1|\2).{4})
```